# Salesforce - Insert Opportunity Products

Tags: apex, data-loader

Need to insert Opportunity Products...Looks like the table in Data Loader is Opportunity Line Items...But I dont' see a way to map the ProductdID?? Am I totally missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice documentation on how to approach this

https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01530000001OdbFAAS

1)First you will need to enable standard price book from Product tabs

2)Create PricebookEntry records

3)Use PricebookEntryId to create opportunity line items

> Data Columns:
>   a. Opportunity ID
>   b. PricebookEntryID
>   c. Total Price
>   d. Quantity